# Editing a file with non .txt extension from python

Tags: python, ansys

I am trying to read a file with the extension .wbjn (ANSYS Workbench journal file) with basically contains python code per se, from python and change some information in it. But python does not recognize the .wbjn file, so I had to rename the .wbjn to .txt and make the changes.

But the problem with this approach is that when I trying to save the .txt extension back to .wbjn, the contents of the file is erased.

How do I do this in a better way ? Is there a library to read files with such extensions or is there another logic to solve this problem ?

Comment: Python's *open()* function pays no heed to the filename or its extension. If you're trying to open it for reading then it merely has to exist. The open mode you specify may be relevant

Comment: What does it mean that "python does not recognize the .wbjn file"? What code are you using to open it? What should the code do? What happens instead?

Comment: I am using open("filename.wbjn","r") to read the file. And print it with print(handle.read()) to display it contents. It works fine but I need to modify it. But if I change the mode to "w" or "a" I get an error saying not readable.

Comment: Please show the error trace. btw - if you open with mode 'w' and you have write permissions it will overwrite the file. If you open with mode 'a' and you have write permissions then any write to the file will append to it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71929486/modifying-variables-in-a-file-with-python 

I tried the following and have described my problem clearly here..Would be great if you could help..Thanks

Comment: Where is the code?